# Why is the std::map insertion so slow compared to c# Dictionary insertion?

Tags: c#, c++, performance, dictionary, stdmap

I am converting my C# library to C++. I am using a C# Dictionary variable across the app, and when I tried using `std::map` instead with string as key in both scenarios, I felt drastic difference in performance.

C# Dictionary took 0.022717 seconds with the below code. C++ map takes around 3 seconds.

C# Dictionary:

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
stopWatch.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    dict.Add(i.ToString(), i);
}
stopWatch.Stop();
var op = stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString();
```

C++ map:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> objMap;

    tm* timetr = new tm();
    time_t t1 = time(NULL);
    localtime_s(timetr, &t1);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        objMap.emplace(std::to_string(i), i);
    }

    tm* timetr2 = new tm();
    time_t t2 = time(NULL);
    localtime_s(timetr2, &t2);

    time_t tt = t2 - t1;
    cout << tt;

    string sss = "";
    cin >> sss;
}
```

Why is there such a difference? What should be an equivalent alternative to achieve the same results?

Comment: How did you compile the c++ version? What optimization flags are you using?

Comment: Note that you are using `time_t` that has a resolution of 1 second. When I try it, I get the result 1.

Comment: Not an answer but `tm* timetr2 = new tm();` -> `tm timetr2;`. Even better use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` to measure time.

Comment: Better would be `map<int, int>` so you aren't accidentally testing string performance.

Comment: when I do on my little raspberry pi the written time is 0 (I removed the useless uses of `localtime_s`) and the input at the end and time indicate 0.32 sec, how can you have 3 seconds ?????

Comment: @bruno It's most probably due to not providing optimization flags.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux doing without any optimization it uses 0.7 sec

Comment: C# dictionaries are hash tables AFAIK. So `std::unordered_map` might be a closer equivalent. I don't think that will increase performance for adding elements though, if anything the opposite.

Comment: @super `std::unordered_map` are a little faster than `std::map`, 0.26 seconds compiled in 02 still on my insect ^^

Comment: use a String as key is so inefficient, change your map key for a int and the performance will increase

Comment: You'll want to look at `std::to_string(i)`, that'll be doing a `malloc` 100000 times.

Comment: @PaulEvans Maybe or it may be using STO. Edit : Or it may not even be building a map, due to the as-if rule not really requiring this code to do anything at all. Edit 2 : I'm now wondering if C# has a similar concept, and whether or not the C# version actually does any work.

Comment: When asking performance-related questions, always mention platform, compiler, and compiler flags used (e.g. -O2). Did you even test in Release mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add my two cents here.

C# dictionary is a HashMap, but C++ std::map is a Red-Black trees. HashMap performs better than tree. If you want to use HashMap in c++, please use std::unordered_map.

Not sure 100% this is the reason, but you can find it out after switch to std::unordered_map.